# how to call a method every second?

Tags: c#, javascript

I am designing a website and I wnat to call this method every secnod,I use the asp.net and don't know any thing about the javascript but I have used this code(tha I get frome google) and it doesn't work!!!
I put all of my code here(it is in webform.aspx)!

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var interval=setInterval(time(),5000);}
</script>
<script  runat="server">
// <![CDATA[

 public void time()
 { 

        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        string hour = date.Hour.ToString();
        string min = date.Minute.ToString();
        string sec = date.Second.ToString();
        time1.Value = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
 }
```

thanks for helps!

Comment: That is not pure javascript, the code you posted is using a library code called jQuery... Did you include it to your page?

Comment: Has your page jquery.js? Because``$(document).ready()`` is jQuery function

Comment: To be clear: You want the web page to call the **server-side** function `time` once every second? That doesn't sound like a very good idea...

Comment: It's strange indeed.. There are syntax errors, replace this line: `var interval=setInterval('time()',5000);});`.

Comment: yes, in here I want to show the time with changing the second,but what should I do,how can I include JQuery to my code?

Comment: jQuery lib is included in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262290/how-to-call-a-method-every-second/16262680#16262680).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't work for these reasons:

- You have `time()` instead of `time` in the `setInterval` call, which will call the function and use the return value as callback instead of using the function as callback.
- You have set the time to five seconds (5000 ms) instead of one second (1000 ms).
- You are missing the closing parenthesis for the `ready` call.
- The function is not Javascript, but C#. You can't call server code directly from client script.

To fix all that (assuming that there is a field with the id `time1` in the page), it would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var interval = setInterval(time, 1000);
});

function time() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  var min = date.getMinutes();
  var sec = date.getSeconds();
  $('#time1').val(hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
}

</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your good notes,I have used your code but it doesn't work,I think that I should include JQuery,but i don't know how and where???

Comment: @sarahsh: You include jQuery using a `script` tag in the `head` element. If you need more information about that, it's well covered in plenty of questions, blogs and tutorials on the web.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: You are right that the global identifier could be avoided, but I chose to keep the code closer to the original to emphasise what really needs fixing.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error problems, and you haven't included jquery.

My example based on your code but with pure javascript:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     var interval=setInterval(time, 5000);
}); // ending ')' was missing
</script>
<script>
function time(){
    var date = new Date();
    alert("Hour is: " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds());
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use strings with `setTimeout`.

Comment: You're right - thanks. There is no need for javascript to eval() on string.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you're getting lots of not-great answers here. *(Edit: I somehow managed to miss [Guffa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16262407/157247), which is pretty good. But as I give more detail than he does, I'll leave this answer. Also, this answer doesn't require jQuery, which apparently the OP isn't [otherwise] using.)*

In JavaScript, to call a function repeatedly, you can either use `setInterval` (which will call it repeatedly) or `setTimeout` (which will call it once) and have the function schedule the next call itself. In both cases, you want to give `setInterval`/`setTimeout` a *function reference*. You don't want to give it a string, and you don't want to *call* the function, which is what the other answers are doing. So:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var elm = document.getElementById("id_of_element_you_want_to_contain_time");

    setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

    function updateTime() {
        var now = new Date(),
            hours = zeropad(now.getHours(), 2),
            minutes = zeropad(now.getMinutes(), 2),
            seconds = zeropad(now.getSeconds(), 2);

        elm.innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }

    function zeropad(str, width) {
        str = String(str);
        while (str.length < width) {
           str = "0" + str;
        }
        return str;
    }
})();
</script>
```

Put that script *below* the element with `id="id_of_element_you_want_to_contain_time"`, so that the element exists when the first line goes to find it.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/esogab/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/esogab/1/edit)

Now, note that whether you use `setInterval` or a series of `setTimeout` calls, either way the time you give will only be done approximately. So if you really want to update something every second, it'll look at bit uneven if you schedule it every second. So you might consider doing it every (say) quarter second (250ms), since what you're doing is not remotely taxing to the browser. [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/esogab/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/esogab/2/edit)

Comment: Why are you saying don't use a string for setinterval?

Comment: @Robbert: There are several reasons. If you use a string with `setInterval` / `setTimeout`, then 1) The browser has to fire up a JavaScript parser to parse it (no big deal), 2) The function you call has to be global (and globals are a Bad Thing), 3) You can't use a minifier/compressor/packer with your code (because they like to rename things with short names). In contrast, if you pass a function reference in, there's no additional parsing, you can use a private function, and you can minify/compress/pack your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use native JavaScript function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // function like your server-side function
    function time () {
        var now = new Date(); 
        console.log(now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds());
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        setInterval(time, 1000)
    };
</script>
```

But you will need know what JavaScript's 1 second will be different from 1 second in real time.

Comment: *"`setInterval(time(), 1000)`"* will *call* the `time` function immediately, and pass its return value into `setTimeout`, just like any other `foo(bar(), 42)` call. You don't want the `()` on `time`, you want to *refer* to the function, not *call* it.